# Difference between some verbs and pronomial forms of the verb with the same translation

Tags: traducción, verbos, preposiciones, reflexivos

SpanishDict translates some verbs and their pronominal forms (+de, +a, etc.) as the same thing. Off the top of my head:

> Escapar - to escape
>
> Escaparse de - to escape
>
> Olvidar - to forget
>
> Olvidarse de - to forget

I've seen this pattern elsewhere. Is there generally an additional meaning associated with the pronominal forms in cases like this? If not a general form, then specifically the examples above, how should they be interpreted?

Comment: The translations with the `de` are totally wrong

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, It has an additional meaning. *De, a, hacia, desde, etc* are prepositions, and they are used to fine tune the verb they are with.

*De* usually points to the passive recipient of the action (I don't know the actual term). For example:

> Escaparse de la policía - To escape from the cops

In this case you're doing the escaping, but the cops are being the ones being escaped from.

> Comer de un plato - To Eat from a plate

Again, in this case you're doing the eating, and the plates is the one being eaten from.

Your examples are not well translated, they should be like

> Escapar - to escape
>
> Escaparse de - to escape *from*
>
> Olvidar - to forget
>
> Olvidarse de - to forget *about*